Bayes Theorem and Total Probability
I'm back for more help....I'm terrible with conditional probability.  Here's a problem from an assignment in a stats course I'm taking:

A U.S. Army Corps of Engineers (USACE) study focused on DDT
contamination of fish in the Tennessee River in Alabama. Part of that
investigation studied how far upstream contaminated fish have
migrated. A fish is considered to be contaminated if its measured DDT
concentration is greater than 5.0 parts per million (ppm).
A) Considering only contaminated fish captured from the Tennessee
River, the data reveal that 52% of the fish are found 275–300 miles
upstream, 39% are found 305–325 miles upstream, and 9% are found
330–350 miles upstream. Use the percentages to estimate the
probabilities P(275–300), P(305–325), and P(330–350).
B) Given that a contaminated fish is found a certain distance
upstream, the probability that it is a channel catfish (CC) is
determined from the data as P(CC|275–300) = 0.775, P(CC|305–325) =
0.77, and P(CC|330–350) = 0.86. If a contaminated channel catfish is captured from the Tennessee River, what is the probability that it was
captured 275–300 miles upstream?

I've sent an email to the instructor with some questions, but in the meantime...
For part A) unless there is some insight I'm missing here the percentages are the probabilities, no?  So $P(275-300) = 0.52$ etc.
For part B) I'm reasonably sure this is another application of Bayes.  We have $P(CC\mid275-300)$ and we're looking for $P(275-300\mid CC)$, right?
So that would work out to be $$P(275-300\mid CC) = \frac{P(CC\mid275-300)\cdot P(275-300)}{P(CC)}$$
But how can we determine $P(CC)$ from the information given?  I'm thinking we can extract that from from the conditional probabilities for CC using total probability?

Yes. (But yes-no questions are considered off topic here...)

I think I have worked this out...
$P(275-300 \mid CC) =$ 
$\frac{P(CC \mid 275-300) \cdot P(275-300)}{P(CC \mid 275-300) \cdot P(275-300) + P(CC \mid 305-325) \cdot P(305-325) + P(CC \mid 330-350) \cdot P(330-350)}$
With all of our givens: 
$P(275-300) = 0.52$ 
$P(305-325) = 0.39$ 
$P(330-350) = 0.09$ 
$P(CC \mid 275-300) = 0.775$ 
$P(CC \mid 305-325) = 0.77$ 
$P(CC \mid 330-350) = 0.86$ 
We get 
$\frac{(0.775) \cdot (0.52)}{(0.775) \cdot (0.52) + (0.77) \cdot (0.39) + (0.86) \cdot (0.09)}$ 
Which comes out to be ~0.516.
